# Como alterar a URL que consome um Webservice?

Tags: c#, web-service

Tenho um Webservice escrito em C# e a aplicação cliente (coletores de dados).

Os coletores consomem o Webservice para consultar informações no BD principal.
Em cada cliente que instalo meu WebService (Servidor de Dados) tem um IP diferente.

Como eu posso parametrizar as aplicações clientes (coletores) via código para consumir o Webservice em um IP diferente do que utilizei pra adicionar as Web References?

Existe alguma forma de alterar via código o IP pra buscar o WebService?

Ex.:

```
MeuWS objColetar = new MeuWS();
objColetar.URL = novoIP;
objColetar.FuncaoColetar(param1, param2);
```

Comment: Lucio, você checou o Web.Config ? Geralmente os endpoints estão cadastrados lá.

Comment: Mas o Web.Config não existe somente em aplicações Web?
A minha aplicação cliente é WindowsCE, então deveria ser App.Config, porém, eu não sei como criar isso.

Comment: entendi, como você não havia explicado, pensei que era uma aplicação que tinha Web.Config ou App.Config... Se houver App.Config, estariam lá.

Comment: Então, mas como eu crio esse app.config ?

Comment: Então, deveria estar criado já, já que você configurou a aplicação. Qual a versão do framework ?

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
MeuWS objColetar = new MeuWS();
objColetar.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(novoIP); // por exemplo, http://129.135.145.177:8080
objColetar.FuncaoColetar(param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
ServiceReferenceAbrasfV201.nfseClient wsClient = 
        new ServiceReferenceAbrasfV201.nfseClient("nfseSOAP1", EnderecoWebService);
```